# i want to activate the function on a click of a button with id="add_city" as of now it activated when Enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to activate the function on a click of a button with id="add_city"
as of now it activated when Enter is pressed..

```
function createCity(stateId, newCity, event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    if (newCity.trim().length) {
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajaxData.php',
        data:{'id': id,
        'country_id': $("#country").val(),
        'state_id': stateId,
        'city': newCity},
        success:function(html){
          $('head').append(html);
          $('#state').change();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a variable and set false value for it
then when button clicked set it's value to true
then in your main function if that variable is true run the rest of code
like below :

```
var isActive=false;
function buttonclicked()
{
 isActive=true;
}
function createCity(stateId, newCity, event) 
{
 if (isActive)
  {
    //rest of code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it by attacing an event to the button:

```
var button = document.getElementById("add_city");
button.addEventListener("click", yourFunction);
```

Remember to wait for page to load before executing that code:

```
document.onload = function () { your code }
```